# Qt incorrectly plots a "sawtooth version" of real data

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a GUI in C++ with Qt that uses QCustomPlots to plot sensor data. They are set up with the following functions:

```
void MainWindow::plotSetup(QCustomPlot *plot, QColor line_color, QString plot_name, float y_min, float y_max, QString y_label) {
     plot->legend->setVisible(true);
     QFont legendFont=font();
     legendFont.setPointSize(9);
     plot->legend->setFont(legendFont);
     plot->legend->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255,255,255,230)));
     plot->axisRect()->insetLayout()->setInsetAlignment(0, Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignTop);

     plot->addGraph();
     plot->graph(0)->setPen(QPen(line_color));
     plot->graph(0)->setName(plot_name);

     QSharedPointer<QCPAxisTickerTime> timeTicker(new QCPAxisTickerTime);
     timeTicker->setTimeFormat("%h:%m:%s");
     plot->xAxis->setTicker(timeTicker);

     plot->axisRect()->setupFullAxesBox();

     plot->xAxis->setLabel("Time");

     plot->yAxis->setRange(y_min, y_max);
     plot->yAxis->setLabel(y_label);

     connect(plot->xAxis, SIGNAL(rangeChanged(QCPRange)), plot->xAxis2, SLOT(setRange(QCPRange)));
     connect(plot->yAxis, SIGNAL(rangeChanged(QCPRange)), plot->yAxis2, SLOT(setRange(QCPRange)));
}
```

I then plot the sensor data with:

```
    mPlot_co2->graph(0)->addData(timestamp, data.co2);
    mPlot_co2->xAxis->setRange(timestamp, sensorDataBufferSize, Qt::AlignRight);
```

Oftentimes the data plots fine, but seemingly at random, it gets "mixed" with this sawtooth pattern (they should all be smooth here, based on the data). The data being plotted doesn't reflect this (I'm printing it to stdout and it doesn't show this). The sawtooth issue will sometimes resolve itself if left alone. Restarting the GUI also makes the issue go away, even though the data stream does not get restarted.

What causes this, and how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Never used QCustomPlot before, but checking out their documentation I wonder if your plot has the [phFastPolylines](https://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/namespaceQCP.html#a5400e5fcb9528d92002ddb938c1f4ef4) hint enabled. Maybe play around with [setPolyHint](https://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCustomPlot.html#a3b7c97bb6c16464e9e15190c07abe9a9) and associated stuff

Comment: I attempted to use phNone and it didn't work, but I could've done it wrong. I put `plot->setPlottingHint(QCP::PlottingHint::phNone, true);` above the `connect(...` line, is that right? When I did that it didn't fix the problem, but when I slowed down the sampling rate it seemed to help, so your hunch might be right.